# Как вернуть значение в input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Как можно не получить, а вернуть значение в input?

Например (может быть не супер пример, но думаю суть ясна):
HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="firstNum">
<input type="number" id="result">
<input type="submit" onclick="CalculateNums()">
```

JS:

```
function CalculateNums() {  
    var a = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;  
    var b = 5;
    var c = document.getElementById("result").value;
    c = a + b;   
    return c;  
}
```

Нужно чтобы взяло значение из 1-го input'a, добавило к нему 5 и вывело результат в второй input

Я начинающий программист, пробовал сам, гуглил, но ничего не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменяя переменную `c`, вы изменяете содержимое самой переменной, а не value у блока.

```js
function CalculateNums() {  
    var a = parseFloat( document.getElementById("firstNum").value );  
    var b = 5;
    
    document.getElementById("result").value = a + b;   
    var c = document.getElementById("result").value;
    
    return c;  
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="firstNum">
<input type="number" id="result">
<input type="submit" onclick="CalculateNums()">
```

И ещё: нужно value приводить в цифренный формат, так-как при получении оно выводит не цифры, а строку

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы установить значение поля ввода (элемента input), нужно присвоить значение его [свойству value](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

```
function CalculateNums() {  
    var a = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;  
    var b = 5;
    var c = document.getElementById("result"); // получаем весь элемент, а не его текущее значение
    c.value = a + b; // устанавливаем свойство value
    return c;  // в данном случае использовать return не обязательно
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```
function saveInputValue() { return input(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Записать просто в поле value

```
document.getElementById("result").value = c;
```